# How to set the duration of audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I am trying to set the duration of an audio tag using HTML DOM duration property of audio.

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:
`$('audio')[0].duration = 1;`

I've gone through other answers but I couldn't see any which make use of the duration property.

If the duration property is readonly, what other method does it leave me with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change the duration as it is locked to the original data (which cannot be changed via the audio element).

You can achieve the illusion of a different duration though by making restrictions on play by monitoring the time and pause the audio when a threshold kicks in:

- Use the [`timeupdate` event](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) and check `currentTime` against your threshold
- You can also use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to poll the same value and do the same check
- Or, for super-accurate timing, you need to use [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), create an audio-buffer for the audio, then use start/stop with the preferred times. This will require CORS requirements to be fulfilled

On the loading side the browser will possibly load the entire file. If you want to control this part you would have to use [Media Source Extension](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/) which allow you to control the buffering process.

Comment: What do you mean by "illusion", could you make an example? I would think this would do almost nothing, you'd still have a progressbar showing the entire duration, and you'd still be able to skip through it ?

Comment: @adeneo i guess "effect" is a better word for it. Assumption being that the controls are not activated or that the element is even attached to DOM.. OP can always make a custom slider for time. (Off-topic: fungerer codementor bra?)

Comment: @K3N - Nja, jeg fikk en invitasjon til Codementor når de startet opp av en eller annen grunn, og registrerte meg, men har brukt det lite. Jeg får e-post hver gang det er noen oppdrag som passer, men innen jeg ser e-posten er problemet som regel løst, slik at jeg har aldri tjent fem øre på det.

Comment: @adeneo ok, godt aa vite. Takk skal du ha!

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to share how I solved. Hope this helps you.
Assume you have an audio element in your HTML (which you can hide):

```
<audio src="source_to_audio_file.mp3" controls="controls" id="audio_el" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

You have another element used to start the play of the audio:

```
<div><a onclick="play_audio('audio_el',2.01,3.2);"></a></div>
```

The function play_audio is below and it takes three parameters: audio_element,time_start,duration

When the element starts to play, the property **value** of the audio element is set to the duration given. You will then use this in the **timeupdate** event to pause the audio.

In the script:

```
var player = document.getElementById("audio_el");  
player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
if (player.currentTime - player._startTime >= player.value){    
      player.pause(); 
 };

});

function play_audio(audio_element,time_start,duration){
var player = document.getElementById(audio_element);
player.value=duration;
player._startTime=time_start;
player.currentTime = time_start;  
player.play();
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me, after fixing the bug: in the div link, it calls play_audio with 4 args but the function only accepts 3 args so the 2nd arg (audio_element) needs to be removed .   I'll edit the answer to fix the bug

Answer (score 0):

```
sound = new Howl({

    src: ['./assets/audio/classic_bell.mp3'], //you can set the custom path 
                                       **OR** 
    src : ['http://...../your url/mp3file.mp3'], //you can also set the url path to set 
                                                 the audio                                                        loop: true,
  });

//in method where you want to play the sound

 this.sound.play();

 setTimeout(()=> {

      this.sound.stop();

  }, 1000);
```

Comment: stop didnt work for me. i replaced with pause() and load().