# JavaScript - how to immediately rewind through recorded audio

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-mediarecorder

I've built a very simple POC for recording an audio file using a microphone and appending the recorded blob into the audio tag element in the browser. The problem is that after recording is done, I can not rewind back and forth until the recording is fully loaded. Looks like there is a problem with duration time. What I want to achieve is something like this on:

https://online-voice-recorder.com/beta/

Right there, after you finish recording, you can immediately rewind to the end of the recording, even if it is 30min long. It works like magic. How can this be achieved?

This is the code I have written (mostly copied from MDN). You can copy-paste to any index.html:

```
<body>
    <button class="record">RECORD</button>
    <button class="stop">STOP</button>
    <div class="clips"></div>
    <script>
    if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
        const record = document.querySelector('.record')
        const stop = document.querySelector('.stop')
        const soundClips = document.querySelector('.clips')

        const constraints = { audio: true };
        let chunks = [];

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then(function (stream) {

                const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/webm' });

                record.onclick = function () {
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                    record.style.background = "red";
                    record.style.color = "black";
                }

                stop.onclick = function () {
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                    record.style.background = "";
                    record.style.color = "";
                }

                mediaRecorder.onstop = function (e) {
                    const clipName = prompt('Enter a name for your sound clip');

                    const clipContainer = document.createElement('article');
                    const clipLabel = document.createElement('p');
                    const audio = document.createElement('audio');
                    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

                    clipContainer.classList.add('clip');
                    audio.setAttribute('controls', '');
                    audio.setAttribute('preload', 'metadata');
                    deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
                    clipLabel.innerHTML = clipName;

                    clipContainer.appendChild(audio);
                    clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);
                    clipContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
                    soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer);

                    audio.controls = true;
                    const blob = new Blob(chunks);
                    chunks = [];
                    const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    audio.src = audioURL;

                    deleteButton.onclick = function (e) {
                        evtTgt = e.target;
                        evtTgt.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(evtTgt.parentNode);
                    }
                }

                mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
                    chunks.push(e.data);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('The following error occurred: ' + err);
            })
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why seeking doesn't work right away

When using a Blob URL, your Audio player does not get any information about the media's duration. I've also found that you [cannot set it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697618/how-to-set-the-duration-of-audio). That will prevent you from *seeking* on the progress bar of native browser Audio controls. So, unfortunately, I believe you cannot use native controls.

### What would be a possible workaround?

What you could do is measure how much time the recording session lasts, and pass that duration to a player controller. That player controller can be an existing one (such as [HowlerJS](https://howlerjs.com/)), or a custom one. The problem with an existing one is that most *(all?)* of them do not support manually setting a duration. There might be another workaround for that if you dig into their code, but for the time being, I thought it would be fun to create a custom player.

**A custom player**

I created a `SoundClip` function which creates the DOM elements of a working player, and allows you to set a URL for the audio, along with its duration, in seconds. Here is how you can use it:

```
// Declare a new SoundClip instance
const audio = new SoundClip();

// Get its DOM player element and append it to some container
someContainer.appendChild(audio.getElement());

// Set the audio Url and duration
audio.setSource(audioURL, duration);
```

### How can you adapt your code to use it

First, you'll have to measure the time it takes for the recording to happen:

```
// At the top of your code, create an Object that will hold that data
const recordingTimes = {};

record.onclick = function() {
    // Record the start time
    recordingTimes.start = +new Date();
    /* ... */
}

stop.onclick = function() {
    // Record the end time
    recordingTimes.end = +new Date();
    // Calculate the duration in seconds
    recordingTimes.duration = (recordingTimes.end - recordingTimes.start) / 1000;
    /* ... */
}
```

Then, instead of using an `audio` DOM element, use a `SoundClip` instance:

```
  mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
    /* ... */
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    // Declare a new SoundClip instance
    const audio = new SoundClip();

    /* ... */

    // Append the SoundClip element to the DOM
    clipContainer.appendChild(audio.getElement());
    clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);

    /* ... */
    const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // Set the audio Url and duration
    audio.setSource(audioURL, recordingTimes.duration);

    /* ... */
  }
```

### And then?

Then, you should be able to do what you want. I provided the full code for the `SoundClip` function and CSS below, but it's pretty basic and not very stylish. You can decide either to customize it to suit your needs, or to go with an existing player on the market, keeping in mind you'll have to hack it to make it work.

### Live demo

https://shrt.tf/so_49886426/

### Full code

This won't work on StackOverflow because it won't allow using the Microphone, but here is the full code:

```js
function SoundClip() {
    const self = {
        dom: {},
        player: {},
        class: 'sound-clip',

        ////////////////////////////////
        // SoundClip basic functions
        ////////////////////////////////

        // ======================
        // Setup the DOM of the player and the player instance
        // [Automatically called on instantiation]
        // ======================
        init: function() {
            //  == Create the DOM elements ==
            // Wrapper
            self.dom.wrapper = self.createElement('div', {
                className: `${self.class} ${self.class}-disabled`
            });
            // Play button
            self.dom.playBtn = self.createElement('div', {
                className: `${self.class}-play-btn`,
                onclick: self.toggle
            }, self.dom.wrapper);
            // Range slider
            self.dom.progress = self.createElement('input', {
                className: `${self.class}-progress`,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                value: 0,
                type: 'range',
                onchange: self.onChange
            }, self.dom.wrapper);
            // Time and duration
            self.dom.time = self.createElement('div', {
                className: `${self.class}-time`,
                innerHTML: '00:00 / 00:00'
            }, self.dom.wrapper);

            self.player.disabled = true;
            //  == Create the Audio player ==
            self.player.instance = new Audio();
            self.player.instance.ontimeupdate = self.onTimeUpdate;
            self.player.instance.onended = self.stop;

            return self;
        },
        // ======================
        // Sets the URL and duration of the audio clip
        // ======================
        setSource: function(url, duration) {
            self.player.url = url;
            self.player.duration = duration;
            self.player.instance.src = self.player.url;
            // Enable the interface
            self.player.disabled = false;
            self.dom.wrapper.classList.remove(`${self.class}-disabled`);
            // Update the duration
            self.onTimeUpdate();
        },
        // ======================
        // Returns the wrapper DOM element
        // ======================
        getElement: function() {
            return self.dom.wrapper;
        },

        ////////////////////////////////
        // Player functions
        ////////////////////////////////

        // ======================
        // Plays or pauses the player
        // ======================
        toggle: function() {
            if (!self.player.disabled) {
                self[self.player.playing ? 'pause' : 'play']();
            }
        },
        // ======================
        // Starts the player
        // ======================
        play: function() {
            if (!self.player.disabled) {
                self.player.playing = true;
                self.dom.playBtn.classList.add(`${self.class}-playing`);
                self.player.instance.play();
            }
        },
        // ======================
        // Pauses the player
        // ======================
        pause: function() {
            if (!self.player.disabled) {
                self.player.playing = false;
                self.dom.playBtn.classList.remove(`${self.class}-playing`);
                self.player.instance.pause();
            }
        },
        // ======================
        // Pauses the player and resets its currentTime
        // ======================
        stop: function() {
            if (!self.player.disabled) {
                self.pause();
                self.seekTo(0);
            }
        },
        // ======================
        // Sets the player's current time
        // ======================
        seekTo: function(sec) {
            if (!self.player.disabled) {
                self.player.instance.currentTime = sec;
            }
        },

        ////////////////////////////////
        // Event handlers
        ////////////////////////////////

        // ======================
        // Called every time the player instance's time gets updated
        // ======================
        onTimeUpdate: function() {
            self.player.currentTime = self.player.instance.currentTime;
            self.dom.progress.value = Math.floor(
                self.player.currentTime / self.player.duration * 100
            );
            self.dom.time.innerHTML = `
                ${self.formatTime(self.player.currentTime)}
                /
                ${self.formatTime(self.player.duration)}
            `;
        },
        // ======================
        // Called every time the user changes the progress bar value
        // ======================
        onChange: function() {
            const sec = self.dom.progress.value / 100 * self.player.duration;
            self.seekTo(sec);
        },

        ////////////////////////////////
        // Utility functions
        ////////////////////////////////

        // ======================
        // Create DOM elements,
        // assign them attributes and append them to a parent
        // ======================
        createElement: function(type, attributes, parent) {
            const el = document.createElement(type);
            if (attributes) {
                Object.assign(el, attributes);
            }
            if (parent) {
                parent.appendChild(el);
            }
            return el;
        },
        // ======================
        // Formats seconds into [hours], minutes and seconds
        // ======================
        formatTime: function(sec) {
            const secInt = parseInt(sec, 10);
            const hours = Math.floor(secInt / 3600);
            const minutes = Math.floor((secInt - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
            const seconds = secInt - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

            return (hours ? (`0${hours}:`).slice(-3) : '') +
                   (`0${minutes}:`).slice(-3) +
                   (`0${seconds}`).slice(-2);
        }
    };

    return self.init();
}

if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
  const record = document.querySelector('.record');
  const stop = document.querySelector('.stop');
  const soundClips = document.querySelector('.clips');
  // Will hold the start time, end time and duration of recording
  const recordingTimes = {};

  const constraints = {
    audio: true
  };
  let chunks = [];

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(function(stream) {

      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        mimeType: 'audio/webm'
      });

      record.onclick = function() {
        // Record the start time
        recordingTimes.start = +new Date();
        mediaRecorder.start();
        record.style.background = "red";
        record.style.color = "black";
      }

      stop.onclick = function() {
        // Record the end time
        recordingTimes.end = +new Date();
        // Calculate the duration in seconds
        recordingTimes.duration = (recordingTimes.end - recordingTimes.start) / 1000;
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        record.style.background = "";
        record.style.color = "";
      }

      mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
        const clipName = prompt('Enter a name for your sound clip');

        const clipContainer = document.createElement('article');
        const clipLabel = document.createElement('p');
        const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        // Declare a new SoundClip
        const audio = new SoundClip();

        clipContainer.classList.add('clip');
        deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
        clipLabel.innerHTML = clipName;

        // Append the SoundClip element to the DOM
        clipContainer.appendChild(audio.getElement());
        clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);
        clipContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
        soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer);

        const blob = new Blob(chunks);
        chunks = [];
        const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // Set the audio Url and duration
        audio.setSource(audioURL, recordingTimes.duration);

        deleteButton.onclick = function(e) {
          evtTgt = e.target;
          evtTgt.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(evtTgt.parentNode);
        }
      }

      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
        chunks.push(e.data);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('The following error occurred: ' + err);
    })
}
```

```css
.sound-clip, .sound-clip * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sound-clip {
    border: 1px solid #9ee0ff;
    padding: .5em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.sound-clip.sound-clip-disabled {
    opacity: .5;
}
.sound-clip-play-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    border: 1px solid #12b2ff;
    color: #12b2ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: .5em;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
.sound-clip-play-btn:before {
    content: "►";
    line-height: 2em;
}
.sound-clip-play-btn.sound-clip-playing:before {
    content: "❚❚";
    line-height: 2em;
}
.sound-clip-play-btn:not(.sound-clip-disabled):hover {
    background: #12b2ff;
    color: #fff;
}
.sound-clip-progress {
    line-height: 2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: calc(100% - 3em);
}
.sound-clip-time {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<button class="record">RECORD</button>
<button class="stop">STOP</button>
<div class="clips"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on @samanime answer, I believe that this line responsible for creating a blob from chunks is the one that takes a lot of time. Instead you can try building blob as you go. This is how you might go about it:

```
<body>
    <button class="record">RECORD</button>
    <button class="stop">STOP</button>
    <div class="clips"></div>
    <script>
    if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
        const record = document.querySelector('.record')
        const stop = document.querySelector('.stop')
        const soundClips = document.querySelector('.clips')

        const constraints = { audio: true };
        let blob = new Blob()

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then(function (stream) {

                const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/webm' });

                record.onclick = function () {
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                    record.style.background = "red";
                    record.style.color = "black";
                }

                stop.onclick = function () {
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                    record.style.background = "";
                    record.style.color = "";
                }

                mediaRecorder.onstop = function (e) {
                    const clipName = prompt('Enter a name for your sound clip');

                    const clipContainer = document.createElement('article');
                    const clipLabel = document.createElement('p');
                    const audio = document.createElement('audio');
                    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

                    clipContainer.classList.add('clip');
                    audio.setAttribute('controls', '');
                    audio.setAttribute('preload', 'metadata');
                    deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
                    clipLabel.innerHTML = clipName;

                    clipContainer.appendChild(audio);
                    clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);
                    clipContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
                    soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer);

                    audio.controls = true;

                    const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    audio.src = audioURL;

                    deleteButton.onclick = function (e) {
                        evtTgt = e.target;
                        evtTgt.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(evtTgt.parentNode);
                    }
                }

                mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
                    blob = new Blob([blob, e.data]);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('The following error occurred: ' + err);
            })
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Unfortunately blob is immutable so you can't really "append" to it as you go, you have to keep recreating a blob. This might or might not be a performance issue.

Comment: It's not _(only)_ a performance issue. I did some tests, and the problem is that the Blob does not contain information about the sound's duration, until you actually play it until the end. I'm working on a solution about that (saving the time in a variable), but the final solution might be a mix between yours and the one I'm working on

Comment: I've tried doing something similar and as @blex has mentioned, Blob does not contain information about the sound's duration. I think that saving recording time is a good idea. I'm not sure if it is possible to explicitly provide duration to the audio element

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code you have doesn't create the `dataURL` until you hit `stop()`. So, if you record for 30 minutes, it could take a while to parse that all.

Instead, what you could do is build up the URL as you are going, and rebuild a new URL as you go. That way, when you hit stop, the URL is basically already done with the last version that is missing the last x-seconds, and when the final one is built, you then swap them out and put them at the same position so they don't even know you swapped (unless they try to go to the very end too quickly).

Beyond that, you could try to get really advanced and try to figure out a way to additively build the URL in pieces without having to create the whole URL in one shot. That would make it a lot faster, but will probably require a good bit of complicated stuff to get correct (not super familiar with the audio formats).

Comment: By URL I think you really mean Blob? Might be worth clarifying.

Comment: Kinda, I was referring to the data URL created from the Blob. Basically, I was imaging always building the URL each time you receive data, so that the last recent one is available. If it can be done at the `Blob` level efficiently instead, even better. Not sure which of the two are the most time intensive.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the response!!